# Output cell written with NotebookWrite dissappears on whole notebook evaluation, yet remains if I individually evaluate it

Tags: front-end, evaluation

Create a new notebook with the following two input cells:

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Manipulator[Dynamic[x]]]], "Output"]]
```

and

```
y = 10  (* dummy cell *)
```

If you evaluate the whole notebook (`Evaluation menu\Evaluate Notebook`), you will see the manipulator appear then quickly disappear.

If you manually evaluate the first cell, the manipulator will not disappear.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotebookWrite` print the cell after the selection. `Evaluate Notebook` select whole notebook and evaluate this. Therefore, your cell is printed in the end of the notebook. Evaluation of the last cell overwrite the output.

You can use `CellPrint[...]` instead of `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], ...]`.